# OnBeforeUnload should not run for some links and buttons

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am using the following JS for confirmation before leaving a page in an MVC application.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'Any Unsaved data will be lost !!';
}
```

This works fine, however I would need this not to run for couple of links and a button. It should take to the new page without any confirmation. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You should pass in the event happening, function(event), and do some kind of sorting on a class for the links that shouldn't trigger the alert.

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I actually got it worked. It is good idea to have a common function :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override handler for specific links, using:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```